# Append or change the return of a proc

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have the following PostgreSQL function that returns a `v_result` as below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_email_text(p_notification_id integer)
  RETURNS character varying AS 
$BODY$
DECLARE
    v_result varchar;

BEGIN  

    SELECT email_text INTO  v_result 
    FROM  public.notification 
    WHERE notification_id = p_notification_id;
    RETURN v_result;

END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
  ALTER FUNCTION  public.get_email_text(integer) OWNER TO test;
```

When you execute this:

```
select public.get_email_text(4673);
```

It produces output like:

```
This email is to notify you that for one or more records has been Requested. Please follow the link below to go directly to this records.  <BR/> <BR/> <BR/>Records Id : Record Name : Subrecord Id : Subrecord Name<BR/><ul><a href = http://localhost:8080/myproject/ShowRecord.action?recordsVO.recordId=3324&recordId=3324&status
=Clearance Requested >3324 </a> : DEV: test record : 2999 : Clearance</ul>
```

Before I return `v_result` I want to remove this from the output:

```
This email is to notify you that for one or more records has been Requested.
```

So that only the rest remains:

```
Please follow the link below to go directly to this records ...
```

Comment: So you want to change the text just in the function return value but not in the table? Is that it? Only for that `p_notification_id`?

Comment: I just want to change the text in the function return  but not in the table. i.e (This email is to notify you that for one or more records has been Requested. Please follow the link below to go directly to this records  to => Please follow the link below to go directly to this records)
Other things in return would remain same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the simpler and cheaper plain [**`replace()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) function while you don't need
the more powerful and more expensive regular expression function `regexp_replace()` (which would interpret the dot (`.`) as placeholder for *any* character).

Also, I suggest this simpler sql function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_email_text(p_notification_id integer)
  RETURNS text AS 
$func$
   SELECT replace(email_text, 'This email is to notify you that ...', '')
   FROM   public.notification 
   WHERE  notification_id = p_notification_id
$func$  LANGUAGE sql;
ALTER FUNCTION public.get_email_text(integer) OWNER TO test;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used below

```
select regexp_replace(v_result, 'This email is to notify you that for one or more titles the Clearance has been Requested.', '') INTO
        v_popup_text;
```